# power-shell problem with conversion int in loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, powershell-2.0

I've got issue. I download file list from s3 bucket and I want to retrive number from a file name and based on some condition do some job. I got the file list and I want to convert file name from string to number but there is issue

```
$Env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="test"
$Env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="test"

$bucketName = "bucket"
$folderName = "directory"
$filename = 20230430162601

$fileList = aws s3api list-objects --bucket $bucketName --prefix $folderName --query 'Contents[].Key' | sort

foreach ($file in $fileList) {
    $name = $file.replace('b-parts/bparts_bmecat_','').replace('.zip', '')
Write-Output $name
}
```

output looks weird in a way i dont know where [] comes from.
[image]

[image]

error im getting but i dont know where "    " comes from I dont see it when printed to screen

Comment: What does the contents of `$filelist` look like before the replace operations? If the `aws` CLI outputs a JSON array, then you probably want to pipe it to `ConvertFrom-Json` _before_ you start sorting

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, sort was the problem. Thank you.